# How to remove duplicate values within a list element in R

Tags: r, list

I need to remove duplicate values within a list element in R.

In the reprex below this would mean I need to remove the second "A" in [[4]].

I have tried to use `unique()`, but this function removes entire elements ([[3]] in the reprex below).

I have been unable to find any SO questions/answers solving my problem.

Minimal reprex:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  a=1:4,
  b=I(list("A", "A", c("A", "B"), c("A", "B", "A"))))

# I need to remove the second "A" in [[4]] 

df$b
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "A" "B" "A"

# unique does not work because it removes [[3]]
unique(df$b)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "A" "B" "A"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `unique()` to the *elements* of `df$b`, not to `df$b` itself.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  a=1:4,
  b=I(list("A", "A", c("A", "B"), c("A", "B", "A"))))

df$b <- lapply(df$b, unique)
df
#>   a    b
#> 1 1    A
#> 2 2    A
#> 3 3 A, B
#> 4 4 A, B
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>